# Three level menu CSS

Tags: css

I want to create a three level menu with CSS but i dont know how to do this:

i have this HTML code with 3 levels :

```
<div class="menu-block-wrapper menu-block-1 menu-name-main-menu parent-mlid-0 menu-level-1">
  <ul class="menu">
  <li class="first leaf active menu-mlid-1264"><a href="#" title="" class="active">Accueil</a></li>
<li class="expanded menu-mlid-1604"><a href="#">Diagnostic RH</a>
<ul class="menu">
<li class="first expanded menu-mlid-1281"><a href="#" title="">Gestion Administrative </a>
<ul class="menu">
<li class="first leaf menu-mlid-958"><a href="#">Remplir le questionnaire</a></li>
<li class="last expanded menu-mlid-1282"><a href="#" title="Gérer les rapports GA">Gérer les rapports</a>
<ul class="menu" style="margin-left: 244px;">
<li class="first last leaf menu-mlid-1287"><a href="#" title="">Saisie des coefficients</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="expanded menu-mlid-1283"><a href="#" title="">Gestion de la paie</a><ul class="menu"><li class="first leaf menu-mlid-1285"><a href="#">Remplir le questionnaire</a></li>
<li class="last leaf menu-mlid-1291"><a href="#" title="Gérer les rapports GP">Gérer les rapports</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="last expanded menu-mlid-1284"><a href="#" title="">Gestion de la rémunération </a>
<ul class="menu"><li class="first leaf menu-mlid-1286"><a href="#">Remplir le questionnaire</a></li>
<li class="last expanded menu-mlid-1290"><a href="#" title="Gérer les rapports GR">Gérer les rapports</a>
<ul class="menu">
<li class="first last leaf menu-mlid-1385"><a href="#">Réponses du panel</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="leaf menu-mlid-1265"><a href="#">Benchmark</a></li>
<li class="leaf menu-mlid-1266"><a href="#">Data-RH</a></li>
<li class="last leaf menu-mlid-1267"><a href="#">Outils et Méthodes</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The result when i hover the first element  all others are open like image :

[image]

In style.css i have this code :

```
nav {
  position: fixed; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 60px; background: url(../rgba.php?r=0&g=0&b=0&a=35) repeat; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.35); z-index: 999;
}
nav * {
  z-index: 999;
}
nav .wrapper {
  padding: 13px 0 0 0;
}
nav .menu {
  float: right; margin-top: -1px;
}
nav li {
  float: left;
}
nav li a {
  padding: 7px 10px 6px; display: block; background: url(../rgba.php?r=0&g=0&b=0&a=30) repeat; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); margin-left: 6px; font-size: 12px;
}
nav li a.active, nav li a:hover {
  background: url(../rgba.php?r=0&g=0&b=0&a=40) repeat; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); color: #fff;
}
#nav-toggle {
  float: right; font-size: 24px; padding-top: 4px;
}
nav ul ul {
  display: none; padding-top: 11px;
}
nav li ul li {
  display: block; float: none;
}
nav  li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
nav  li ul li:hover ul{
    display:none;
}
nav ul ul {
    list-style: none;
}
nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
}
nav li:hover  ul li ul{
    margin-left: 222px;
    width: 250px;
}
nav li ul li:hover ul{
    margin-left: 222px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

Please help me  how to solve it!

Comment: From first glance it seems you need to set sub-ULs to be hidden by default, and only shown on hover to the parent, e.g. `li:hover > ul { display: block; }`

Comment: In the end whether you've succeed doing it or not, I would not recommend a menu layout like this. It is so old fashioned and Three level is insane for this dropdown menus. There should be another alternative to do this. Whether by categorizing things from start or to choose different menu layout for this subject.